# Update text in dynamically created label

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a proof of concept type situation that will eventually be tied to a scheduling database.  As a Test I created this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'AddButton("test")
    addLots()
End Sub

Private Sub AddLots()
    Dim x As Integer
    For x = 0 To 10
      Dim b As New Button
      Dim newLabel As New Label
      newLabel.Location = New Point(100, x * 20)
      newLabel.Name = x
      newLabel.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
      newLabel.Text = newLabel.Name
      Me.Controls.Add(newLabel)
      Me.Controls.Add(b)
      b.Location = New Point(20, x * 20)
      b.Text = x
      b.Tag = x
      b.Name = x
      AddHandler b.Click, AddressOf Button_Click
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Button_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim B As Button = sender
    MsgBox(B.Name)
End Sub
```

For this proof of concept, I simply want label 1 text to be updated when I press button 1 seems like a simple process but it's kicking my butt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for any object, to affect a `Label` you will need a reference to it.  As it stands, the only reference you have is via the `Controls` collection of the parent control you added the `Label` to, i.e. the form itself.  You could loop through the `Controls` of the form and as soon as you find a `Label` then you know you have the first one, or you could call `OfType` and `First` or `FirstOrDefault`.  That assumes that there are no other `Label` controls on the form.

You might also consider using a dedicated parent control so that you know it will only contain the `Label` controls you created at run time.  The obvious choice would be a `TableLayoutPanel` because it will handle the layout for you too.

If accessing the dynamic controls via a `Controls` collection is an issue then keep your own collection.  Declare a member variable of type `List(Of Label)` and add each `Label` you create to it.  You can then access your control from that collection and know that there are no other controls in there to get mixed up with.

By the way, if you're creating those controls at run time then they won't be automatically disposed when the form is.  Make sure that you dispose them yourself and also use `RemoveHandler` for each `AddHandler` you used.

Actually, looking closer at your code, I just realised that there's a 1:1 correspondence between the `Button` and `Label` controls.  It would make sense to use that.  Two options are to assign the corresponding `Label` to the `Tag` of each `Button` or else use a `Dictionary(Of Button, Label)` assigned to a member variable to store the relationships.  That way, you can then use the `sender` in the event handler, which will be the `Button` that was clicked, to get the corresponding `Label`.

Option 1.

Creating the `Label`:

```
Dim btn As New Button
Dim lbl As New Label

btn.Tag = lbl
```

In the event handler:

```
Dim btn = DirectCast(sender, Button)
Dim lbl = DirectCast(btn.Tag, Label)
```

Option 2.

At class level:

```
Private labelsByButton As New Dictionary(Of Button, Label)
```

Creating the `Label`:

```
Dim btn As New Button
Dim lbl As New Label

Me.labelsByButton.Add(btn, lbl)
```

In the event handler:

```
Dim btn = DirectCast(sender, Button)
Dim lbl = Me.labelsByButton(btn)
```

Comment: Ahhh, That helped, tanks,

Answer (score 0):

I added this to the button click event.  Doesn't seem very efficient as I will eventually have 30-40 buttons and controls on the form but it works.

```
  Private Sub Button_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
      Dim B As Button = sender
      Dim lblToChange As Integer = B.Name
      For Each objCtrl As Control In Me.Controls
          If TypeOf objCtrl Is Label Then
             Dim Lbl As Label = DirectCast(objCtrl, Label)
             If Lbl.Name = lblToChange Then
                Lbl.Text = "This ONe"
             End If
          End If
      Next
   End Sub
```